# Can't load Microsoft.Data.Services.Client exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I have an MVC site hosted as a cloud service in Azure. Users are logged in via single sign-on using there AD accounts.

In chrome this is working fine but when i access the site via IE I get the following

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Version=5.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I don't understand how the same server side code has different results in different browsers.

The error appears to happen in when i override the Authenticate method in System.Security.Claims.ClaimsAuthenticationManager.

We do this to check if the user has a certain AD role and then if so just call base.Authenticate which is where the exception gets thrown.

Stack Trace:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Version=5.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
...GraphClaimsAuthenticationManager.Authenticate(String resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal) in ...Azure.Helpers\GraphClaimsAuthenticationManager.cs:76
System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequestBase request) +694
System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args) +103571
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +92
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

**Update**

I think I have partially worked it out, the Dll is not being build into the Azure Cloud Service package. Copy Local is set to true and it gets output when i build locally. Not sure why it isn't included though.

Comment: Can you please provide the exception stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that you have deployed `Microsoft.Data.Services.Client` dll if your project used this dll.

Based on my understanding, override the `ClaimsAuthenticationManager.Authenticate` doesn't require this dll. And this error is a server side issue, the browser will not cause this issue, please ensure that you were access the same app using the different web browser.

Comment: Your first sentence has helped Fei Xue, now just to work out why it isn't being deployed.